# Find links to nonexistent pages in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, wiki

I have been searching for a few days and it is hard to find specifics for wikimedia.

Does anyone know of an extension, or report that will show internal links to nonexistent pages?

We host a wiki where we have users that have crated some excellent content, but to have to go through each page to find the links to pages that have not been created yet is next to impossible due to the amount of content.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your [`Special:SpecialPages` list](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special%3aSpecialPages) and you will find

- `Wanted categories`
- `Wanted files`
- **`Wanted pages`**
- `Wanted templates`

which are (more or less) dynamic lists of all redlinks in your wiki.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I even glanced over that but was looking for the word links...  Again, thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only see a list of dead links for a specific page or a group of pages, you can use [DynamicPageList](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aDynamicPageList_%28third-party%29) to run a `linksfrom` query with `openreferences = yes`. Go here for more info: http://semeb.com/dpldemo/index.php?title=DPL:Manual_-_DPL_parameters:_Criteria_for_page_selection#linksfrom